# The number of holomorphic coverings (with given degree) of the punctured sphere is finite.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, alternative-proof, covering-spaces

I'm looking  for a  proof of the following theorem:

> Fix a finite set $B=\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\}\subseteq \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$, then there is only a finite number of isomoprhism classes of holomorphic coverings of $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ with the following properties:
>
> 1. Their branch locus is contained in $B$
> 2. They have the same degree $d$

One way to proceed is by proving the correspondence between coverings and monodromy representations (see Miranda's book), but this way is a bit long and moreover it demonstrates much more than I want. **I'm interested only on the cardinality of the set of all possible holomorphic coverings of given degree (up to isomorphism)**. Is there a 'quick way' to prove the above theorem?

**Addendum:**
I need that result only when $k=3$, namely $B=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$,  therefore I will accept also answers for this particular case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about $z\mapsto z^n$ ? They are all different with branch locus $0$ and $\infty$

Comment: in the old-fashioned way you can cut along some branch cuts (so that the complement is 1-connected, and thus the cut covering is trivial) and then reglue the branches - this gives finitely many possibilities (that is, for a given degree of the covering)

Comment: The degree of the coverings must be fixed, I will edit the question. I'm sorry

Comment: Now the question is written in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to: how many subgroups of index $d$ does the free group $F_n$ on $n$ elements have, up to conjugacy? This question is extremely difficult to answer precisely. However, one does have:

> **Theorem**. Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Then $G$ has finitely many subgroups of a given index $d$.

*Proof*: The left action of $G$ on cosets identifies subgroups of $G$ of index $d$ with a subset of the set of representations $G \to S_d$. Since $S_d$ is finite and $G$ is finitely generated, there are finitely many such representations.

> **Corollary** $F_n$ has finitely many subgroups of index $d$.

However, giving estimates for these numbers is very hard. Suppose you want to count only normal subgroups of $F_n$, for instance. Then you are asking: how many finite groups of order $d$ can be generated by $n$ elements? Counting finite groups is not a light task - usually the only way of counting groups is to list them, and this problem is essentially the problem of the classification of finite groups.

Comment: Why cant two different subgroups give the same representation ?

Comment: Dear @Rene: You can recover the subgroup from the representation: it is simply the kernel of the representation.

Comment: But it might not be normal.

Comment: Do conjugate subgroups give equivalent coverings ?

Comment: Dear @Rene: Oops, you are right! I should have said: one can recover the subgroup as the *stabilizer* of the trivial coset $1 \in \{1, \dots, d\}$ (which coincides with the kernel of the action only if the subgroup is normal).

Comment: Ok, this brings me back to my previous question since if you take the stabiliser of a non identity element it is a conjugate of the subgroup. I dont see how you can distinguish between $1$ and another element, but in any case there will only be finitely many possibilities, so you have the claim.

Comment: Dear @Rene: I believe that conjugate subgroups do give equivalent coverings, though non canonically (depending on a choice of base point away from the bad points). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by non canonically.

Comment: Another comment, sorry, but arent you showing the more general, that there are finitely many unbranched coverings of the punctured sphere ?